# log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment)

Tags: java, spring, maven, logging, log4j

I am trying configure the log4j in my spring project, but after include this in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

and this file log4j2.xml in my classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

when I deploy the application, this message is displayed in the console (and no log message):

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I visit the indicated link, but the info in it don't help me.

Anyone knows what I miss?

ps.: In my classes, I add this line too:

```
static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(AcessoService.class.getName());
```

and add:

```
logger.error(...);
```

in the places I wanted, but as I said, no log message is displayed in the console.

**UPDATE**

Now I correct the name of the file to log4j.xml and the error message change to:

```
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 2 and column 30
log4j:WARN O elemento-raiz do documento "Configuration" deve corresponder à raiz de DOCTYPE "null".
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 2 and column 30
log4j:WARN O documento é inválido: nenhuma gramática encontrada.
log4j:ERROR DOM element is - not a <log4j:configuration> element.
```

**UPDATE 2**

the file below corrects the second error, but I returned to the first one I post here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" debug="true" xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new error is about the content of the log4j.xml file.
Your root Configuration element has no namespace declaration:

```
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
                     xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
```

Can this help?

Comment: yes, fixed the second error message, but returned to the first one. Strange that the content of the file is similar to the one available in the official site: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Answer (score 3):

You have a file named log4j2.xml (with an exta "2" in the end.). By default Spring loads the log4j.properties or log4j.xml from the class path. If you want to load a different file, you have to tell Spring to pick that up. A sample example is given below.

In your web.xml,

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j2.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

See http://javafindings.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/integrating-log4j-with-spring-3-0-mvc/

Comment: Spring is able to find log4j2.xml that's why its giving parsing error. I think Spring expecting for log4j v1 but found log4j v2. How to resolve it?